# Different result between grep and python with the same regex statement

Tags: python, regex, grep

Why the same regex statement, get different result between Python and grep?

My input string is like as below:

**statement or comment should appear in default case [MISRA 2012 Rule 16.1, required], [MISRA 2012 Rule 16.4, required]**

The purpose is to find **[MISRA 2012 Rule 16.1, required]** and **[MISRA 2012 Rule 16.4, required]** by regex.

Using the code as below in Python,

```
onelineStr = "statement or comment should appear in default case [MISRA 2012 Rule 16.1, required], [MISRA 2012 Rule 16.4, required]"
r1 = re.findall(r"\[MISRA.*?\]", onelineStr)
print (r1)
```

the result is shown as below, which is as my expectation.

```
['[MISRA 2012 Rule 16.1, required]', '[MISRA 2012 Rule 16.4, required]']
```

However, when I use the same statement of regex in grep. Nothing I can find.

```
grep -o --color "\[MISRA.*?\]" 1.txt
```

The content of 1.txt is **statement or comment should appear in default case [MISRA 2012 Rule 16.1, required], [MISRA 2012 Rule 16.4, required]**

Is anything wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: Use `grep -Eo`, with `-E` flag as well.

Comment: You don't need to use \. grep is treating the string you input as regex by default :)

Comment: grep doesn't support non-greedy for at least one difference, see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: if you have `GNU grep` with PCRE support, you can use `grep -oP '\[MISRA.*?\]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*?` lazy dot pattern matches any 0 or more chars (other than line break chars) as few as possible, but *lazy quantifiers* are not supported in POSIX regular expressions.

You need to use a `[^][]*` in `grep` in a POSIX BRE pattern to match zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`:

```
grep -o --color "\[MISRA[^][]*]" 1.txt
```

Actually, the same pattern can be used in Python `re`, too.

`[^][]*` is an example of "smart placement" of special chars inside a bracket expression (POSIX bracket expressions do not allow regex escape sequences).